# keeping multiple checkboxes of the same name checked in foreach loop in php

Tags: php, checkbox

I have already asked this  question,but couldn’t find the solution.Made some modification in the code.Kindly give me a solution. I need to keep the selected check-boxes checked after the form submission. The code is as below. Please help.

```
     <? $i=0;
        while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC))
        {

            $id="chkbox".$i;
      ?>
          <input type="checkbox" name="chkbx" onclick ="func()" id="<?echo   $id;">? value="<?echo $val \n;?>" <? echo "$val";?>
     <? $i=$i+1

     }
     ?>
```

Now where and how to include the checked property of the boxes..

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<? $i=0;
$chkbox = array();
       if(isset($_SUBMIT))  
            $chkbox = $_POST['chkbx'];
       while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC))
        {
            $checked ='';
            $id="chkbox".$i;
            if(in_array($val,$chkbox))
             $checked = 'checked="checked"';
      ?>
          <input type="checkbox" name="chkbx[]" onclick ="func()" id="<?php echo $id;?>" value="<?php echo $val \n;?>"  <?php echo $checked;?> ><?php echo "$val";?>
     <? $i=$i+1

     }
     ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use attribute "checked" for selected checkboxes and add [] to name attribute to convert a single attribute to array of values:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="chkbx[]" ...... >
```